# how can i use livewire component in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

how can I use the livewire component in the controller?

```
$payment = Basket::where('id', $id)->first();
        $orderCode = $payment['order_code'];
        $transaction = Transaction::where('order_code', $orderCode)->first();

        $data = [
            $transaction,
            Auth::guard('customer')->user()
        ];

        // use livewire component

        Notification::send(User::where('position', '=', [17, 19, 20])->get(), new CreditRequestNotification($data));

        return view('user.payment.payment_kind', compact('payment', 'transaction'));
```

I want use livewire component in where that commented

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow my dear new friend, your question is vague, you return a usual view in the last line, you must change it with the livewire component, please see https://laravel-livewire.com/

Comment: You can't use a Livewire component inside a controller method. Livewire components are either rendered in a view (in blade), or rendered from a route (making it a full-page component)

Answer (score 0):

it is wrong:

```
User::where('position', '=', [17, 19, 20])->get()
```

use:

```
User::whereIn('position', [17, 19, 20])->get()
```